# How can I write an IF statement with two possibilities

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programer and am trying to write a program that will put users into their key stage in school based on their year. The answer may be very simple but I'm a beginner so I would really appreciate your help.

This is the code I've written for it:

```
 answer = int(input("What year are you in?"))
 if answer < 7 or 8 or 9:
     print("You are in Key Stage 3")
 elif answer < 10 or 11:
     print("You are in Key Stage 4")
 else:
     print("You are in Key Stage 5")
```

Year 7-9 is key stage 3, year 10-11 is key stage 4 and year 12-13 is key stage 5. The program is supposed to output 'key stage' 3, 4 or 5 depending on what the user put in. Whenever i put in any year it outputs key stage 3, even if I input '11' or '13' which it shouldn't.

Comment: if answer in (7,8,9)

Comment: This does not work since he is checking for answer < 7

Comment: Why do you write ```if answer < 7 or 8 or 9:```? I see what you mean to do there, and the line ```if answer < =9 and answer > =7:``` does the same. Or as suggested you can use ```if answer in (7, 8, 9): ```

Comment: Instead of doing `if answer < =9 and answer > =7:` we could use `if 7 <= answer <= 9:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if answer in (7, 8, 9):
     print("You are in Key Stage 3")
elif answer in (10, 11):
     print("You are in Key Stage 4")
else:
     print("You are in Key Stage 5")
```

or this :

```
if 7 <= answer <= 9:
     print("You are in Key Stage 3")
elif 10 <= answer <= 11:
     print("You are in Key Stage 4")
else:
     print("You are in Key Stage 5")
```

Comment: This does not work since he is checking for answer < 7 and < 10

Comment: @Carsten He told in description : **Year 7-9 is key stage 3**